# Dot notation in Python. Should method come before or after the object?

Tags: python, methods, notation

I am learning Python, and I'm trying to simulate a card game.
I have a question regarding dot notation. I have looked all over the internet for a specific answer but was unable to find one.

Why is it, that sometimes we are taught to call a method in dot notation like this:

```
object.methodName()
```

While other times we are shown to call it like this:

```
className.methodName(object)
```

What is the difference?

Here is a specific example. This is a method definition from the book (How to think like a Computer Scientist)

```
class Hand(Deck):
    def __init__ (self, name = " "):
        self.cards = []
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        s = "Hand "+ self.name
        if self.isEmpty():
            return s+" is empty\n"
        else:
            return s+ " contains\n" + Deck.__str__(self)
```

Sometimes the object comes before the method:

```
self.isEmpty()
```

Sometimes the object comes after the method, in the parenthesis:

```
Deck.__str__(self)
```

Which method do we use? Does it matter?

Comment: `Deck` is a *class*, and `Deck.__str__` is an unbound method. If you tried `self.__str__()` instead you'd be calling the `Hand.__str__()` method again (causing an infinite recursion error), you want the parent class, so it is called explicitly.

Comment: However, calling the class like that is not recommended. Use `super().__str__()` instead (and let `super()` figure out what the parent class is and how to find `Deck.__str__` to `self` properly).

Comment: You overrode the `__str__` method in the `Hand` subclass so this is needed to call the parent version of `__str__`. As mentioned, you should do `super().__str__()` instead as it deals with more complicated inheritance structures.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters @ tdelaney   Thank you! I think I understand. Yes, 'Deck' is the parent class for 'Hand'. We have not yet been taught about about 'super()'.  I looked it up on [link](docs.python.org). And yes, where you see 'Deck.__str__(self)', we are trying to access the string formatting for 'Deck', the parent class. So now I understand why it was written that way and I now understand that it is recommended that we use 'super()' for this purpose. The appropriate syntax for using super() in this case would be: 'super().__str__(self)'   ?

Comment: One last newb question, how did you get your code to display like that, in greyscale in your comments? I thought 'quotes' would do it.

Comment: @M.Copeland: No, it's `super().__str__()`. This'll bind the right method from your next parent class (in Method Resolution Order) to `self`, so you don't need to pass in `self` manually. When you add a comment, there's a help link you can check for formatting information; code is marked up with \` backticks.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters  Ok, I will play around with it. Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

> Sometimes the object comes after the method, in the parenthesis:

```
Deck.__str__(self)
```

No, the object always comes before its own method. There are two python "objects" in this line. You are passing the `self` object (which is really a class instance) as a parameter to the `__str__` method of the `Deck` object (which is really a class).

Answer (score 1):

Wenn you use:

```
 object.methodName()
```

then you calling the method of a special instance with it's own data.
As the method is related to the given instance you get different results.

```
a = Hand()
b = Hand()
```

then

```
a.cards
b.cards
```

may be different (in most cases).

To access this data the object self has to put in every method.
This is done by:

```
def foo(self):
    return self.cards
```

When you define the method.

Unless you don't write a special class method than you always have to put the self there.

When calling `object.methodName()` the method automatically gets the information of the object it belongs to (because you hand the object/instance reference over before the dot. This information is stored in the parameter `self`. Thus the method can for example do: `return self.cards`

But if you call it like `Deck.__str__(self)` than you only have the class this means there is no `self` (which is the object reference itself).

So the method does not know which instance data it belongs to, therefore you have to hand over the `self`.

So summed up, if you call:
`object.__str__()` the information about the instance is given because you used the object reference to call the method.

But if you use `Deck` resp. the `className` than you have to put the information about the instance also via `className.method(self)` because otherwise there is no object reference for an object instance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the object comes first.

Like this:

`object.methodName()`

Or like this:

`self.isEmpty()`

But I wanted to know why my Python book is teaching me to call this one method like this:

`Deck.__str__(self)`

I wanted to know why "self" is in parentheses at the end, instead of at the beginning of the method. In other words, why not write it like this:

`self.Deck._str_()`

The reason, is that the code above would throw an error:

`"Hand instance has no attribute Deck`

The above error is caused because written this way, Python thinks that "Deck" is an attribute of self. But in this case it is not. Deck, is the PARENT type to the Hand type, it is not an attribute of self.

Here is the code block where you can see the code in question, as well as the parent type (Deck) and the child type I am working with (Hand). In this code, we are writing a method to overwrite the string formatting for Hand, by accessing the string formatting in Deck. The code snippet `Deck.__str__(self)`
is written this way because we need a way to tell Python which type object we would like it to copy the string formatting from. In this case, we wanted the string formatting from Deck, the parent.

`class Hand(Deck):
    def __init__ (self, name = " "):
        self.cards = []
        self.name = name`

```
def __str__(self):
    s = "Hand "+ self.name
    if self.isEmpty():
        return s+" is empty\n"
    else:
        return s+ " contains\n" + Deck.__str__(self)
```

Also, as stated by @ Martijn Pieters, using SUPER: `super().__str__()` is better than doing it the way I did: `Deck.__str__(self)`
We have not yet learned Super, but you can learn more about it here(https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super). Super basically tells Python to find the parent formatting for you, and use that. Much easier!

I hope that this explanation is understandable. I tried to over-explain to make up for anything that is not clear :-/